# Metaploit: Exploits and its relevant payload

Tags: metasploit

How can I find out what payload(s) can be use/executed along with an exploit?

For example, I can use an exploit called exploit/windows/smb/ms08_067_netapi. Right after that I set the payload to windows/adduser. What other payload can I use here. How can I find out this information or is there a specific command in Metasploit that I can run to figure this out?

I am not asking specifically for the ms08_067_netapi exploit.

Thank you

Comment: [`show payloads` shows compatible payloads.](http://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/Msfconsole_Commands#payloads)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check also [here](http://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/Using_Exploits) you can see that when you are 'inside' the exploit you want to use by hitting 'show payloads' it gives you back the compatible payloads with that exploit.

Comment: thanks! although, i can't find windows/adduser when i run this command, i think you're right.

Comment: Same with me,so propably that payload is not compatible

Comment: it does work. i tested the exploits together with the payload on winXP SP3 - after watching a video :)